# How can I compile opencv from source at Win 10

Tags: opencv

I read [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) and [this](https://perso.uclouvain.be/allan.barrea/opencv/cmake_config.html), and saw the videos, but looks I did not understand the required :(

I need to compile opencv from source in order to be able to use [CV-Rust](https://github.com/nebgnahz/cv-rs) at my application, what I did is:

1- Downloaded and installed [Visual Studio 2015](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015) with Visual C++ option.

2- Downloaded and installed [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

3- Downloaded and installed [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

4- Downloaded and installed [Tortoisegit](https://tortoisegit.org/download/)

5- Downloaded and installed [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)

6- Downloaded and installed [Miktex](https://miktex.org/download)

7- Downloaded and installed [DoxyGen](http://www.doxygen.org/)

8- Upgraded the pip `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and installed the below packages:

8-1- [Setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#files) as `pip install setuptools`

8-2- [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) as `pip install -U Sphinx`

8-3- [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) as `pip install NumPy`

9- Downloaded and extracted the following, and put all the extracted folders in a seperate folder called it `dep`:

9-1- [Threading Building Blocks 2018 Update 6 _win.zip](https://github.com/01org/tbb/releases)

9-2- [OpenEXR .tar.gz](http://www.openexr.com/downloads.html)

9-3- [Eigen .zip](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Download)

10- Downloaded and unzipped the [OpenCV winpack](https://opencv.org/opencv-3-4-1.html)

11- Closed in another folder the [OpenCV github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) using Tortoisegit

What is required now!

Comment: Comliler and CMake (GUI in the beginning) are the only important things. After you compiled the basic version you can try adding cuda and other fancy stuff.

Comment: Agree with Micka (personally I'd even avoid the GUI, a simple shell script to run CMake with all the appropriate arguments works will). | Doanloading TBB and OpenEXR seems pointless -- on windows they're either included with the source, or the build system fetches them automagically. Downloading the "OpenCV winpack" seems redundant if you already use Git to fetch the sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the issue I raised at [github](https://github.com/nebgnahz/cv-rs/issues/94) and its solution below:

It looks I was having some conflicts in my machine setup:

I was not having required permission to execute scripts as the `PS`, so I added the required permission as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core), by writing:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Also, I was installing `VS2017` and `VS2015` which was appeared to be causing some kind of conflict, so I uninstalled `VS2017` as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) and removed `Win10 SDK` as well.

Confirmed `Cmake` is installed properly and added to the path, by running `cmake -version`

Then I downloaded the [cv-rs](https://github.com/nebgnahz/cv-rs) repository.

Then created directory `C:\opencv`

In the file explorer, enabled see `hidden` folders, to see the `.git`

Then copied both `.git` and `.windows` folders to the `C:\opencv`

[image]

Opened `powershell` console as administrator in `c:\opencv`

Run the below commands in PS:

```
PS C:\opencv> git reset --hard
PS C:\opencv> git submodule update
PS C:\opencv> .\.windows\msvc_2_build_OCV.ps1 -EnableCuda $False -Compiler vc14
```

[image]

It will take sometime running the script and configuring opencv.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Having both MSVS15 and MSVS17 shouldn't be an issue -- got even more versions in parallel here, you just have to tell CMake which one to use. | Copyiing `.git` directories around, and then having to run `git reset --hard`.... that just sounds mighty suspect.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek actually it looks my previous installation of `VS2017` was not complete, and this is why I was stuck when running the script with `vc15`